# file is not downloading blob link

Tags: javascript, file, download, blob, using

I have below snippet that download the "Test.csv" in IE11, CHROME very well.
But nothing happens in case of FIREFOX 39.0

Any Help will be appreciated.

```
var blob = new Blob([], { type: 'text/csv' });

/* It will work for IE versions
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Test.csv');
*/

var link = document.createElement("a");

//link.setAttribute("onclick","alert('Click Fired')");   

link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'Test.csv';
link.click();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rq8460cL/2/

Answer (score 3):

I seems like you have to add the link to the dom before you click it

```
var blob = new Blob([], { type: 'text/csv' });

/* It will work for IE versions
window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Test.csv');
*/

var link = document.createElement("a");

//link.setAttribute("onclick","alert('Click Fired')");   

link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = 'Test.csv';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rq8460cL/3/